# How to calculate Limit Points of a set?

Tags: general-topology

How can I calculate limit points of $$Y=\left\{ \dfrac{x}{1 + \lvert x \rvert} \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$

I know the definition but when subjected such sets I don't see a way how to apply them.

Comment: It would be better to replace the brace for parenthesis, since braces are used generically as "sets".

Comment: This is a set, better use a capital $Y$ and keep braces. Study the function $f(x)$ can you show it is continuous, increasing and limits in $\pm\infty$ are $\pm 1$.

Comment: $x/1$ is just $x$. Did you mean $x/(1+|x|)$?

Comment: I'd start by writing down examples of what numbers are in this set. It's helpful to get an idea of what you think the limit points should be, then you can show they are the limit points.

Comment: This might also be helpful https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%2F%281%2B%7Cx%7C%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints : Think that Range$(Y)=(-1,1) $
Now , what is the limit points of $(-1,1)$?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your definition of limit point is similar to "A limit point, x, of a set, A, is a point about which every open ball contains a point of A other than x."

This would be an interval in $\mathbb{R^1}$ or a disk in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

The set $Y=\left\{ \dfrac{x}{1 + \lvert x \rvert} \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R^1} = \mathbb{R}$.

To find a limit point of $Y$, you must find the points, about which there is an interval, containing that point and another of $Y$.

The points contained in $Y$ are the same as the points in the range of a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, defined by $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{1 + \lvert x \rvert}$.

The range of this function is the interval $(-1,1)$  in $\mathbb{R^1}$.

Solving this problem is equivalent to finding the limit points of the interval $(-1,1)$ in $\mathbb{R^1}$.  Consider the points between -1 and 1, not including these end points.  Call one of these x.  Thus $-1 < x < 1$.  In $\mathbb{R^1}$, for any distance (a positive real number), h, from x, you can find a point of $(-1,1)$. The interval under consideration is $(x-h,x+h)$.  To simplify this, consider only half of the interval $(x,x+h)$.  A similar argument to the following could be applied equally well to the other half of the interval.

Assume $x+h < 1$.  Then $x < x+h < 1$ and $2x < 2x + h < 2x + 2h = 2(x+h)$.  This implies that $\frac{2x+h}{2} \in (x, x+h)$.  If we choose a point

$z = \dfrac{2x+h}{2-2x-h} \in \mathbb{R}$, then $p = \dfrac{z}{1+\lvert z \rvert} = \dfrac{2x+h}{2}\in Y$.

Hence, for any point,$x$, in $(-1, 1)$ and for every open interval about $x$, there exists a point $p$, such that $p\in (-1,1) = Y$.  Hence every $x\in Y$ is a limit point of Y.

If you consider the end point $-1$, a similar argument can be used to show that in the interval (-1, h-1), there is a point $p \neq -1$ in $(-1,1)$ for every $h\in \mathbb{R}$, $h>0$.  From which it follows that $-1$ is a limit point of $Y$.

Using the interval $(1-h,1)$, $h\in \mathbb{R}, h>0$ it may also be shown that $1$ is a limit point of $Y$.